# how can i use a fontawesome icon as link?

Tags: html

i use fontawesome icons on my website. i would like to add a link to this icons.

for example : when someone clicks on the google icon the google page should open in a new window.

```html
<div id="GooglePlus">
 <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
</div>
```

```html
href="http://google.com" target="_blank"
```

how can i combine this two things ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="GooglePlus">
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I would reccomend [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com).  I learned all I know from this website and W3Schools.com.  Good luck!